# Running catkin over fuerte

Tags: catkin, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using Fuerte over Ubuntu 12.04. I have been building my packages with Rosbuild but now I have to use Catkin as some of the packages that I need are only released for Groovy.

Inside opt/ros/fuerte/share I have a folder named catkin. Do I need to build this package? I have tried but it doesn't have a Makefile.

As I didn't succeeded in building this package I got Catkin source code from GitHub (release for Fuerte) and tried to build it with Rosbuild but It doesn't have a Makefile either.

I have also followed several tutorials for using Catkin in Fuerte but it is not clear to me how to create a Catkin workspace and if this is the origin of my problems. I have tried to follow the instructions at: ros.org/wiki/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace, but I get an error when executing catkin_init_workspace. The system doesn't recognize the command.

Thank you very much in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61534/running-catkin-over-fuerte/) by [mpalomino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4757/mpalomino/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-04-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not recommend using `catkin` in Fuerte. If you want/need to use `catkin` then you should update to Groovy. The reason the `catkin_init_workspace` command is not found is because the version in Fuerte does not have that command.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2013-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mpalomino](https://answers.ros.org/users/4757/mpalomino/) on 2013-04-26**:
Ok. Thank you very much. We will update to Groovy.